# Ajax post method for dynamically delete

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, post

There's a mysql database, and I would like to delete dynamic with ajax post method.

Here is button for the action in the table.php

```
print "<td class='centered_button'>
<button> onclick='requestD(".$row['modify_id']. ")'>Törlés</button>
</td>";
```

The function from javascript.js

```
function requestD(id){
    var conf = confirm("Biztosan törli a kérelmet?");
    if (conf){
        $.post("request_delete.php", {modify_id: id});
    }
}
```

The request_delete.php

```
<?php 
require_once ('config/connect.php');
if(isset($_POST['modify_id']){
    $modify_id = $_POST['modify_id'];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM gy_modify WHERE modify_id='$modify_id'";
    mysqli_query($link,$sql);
}
?>
```

The confirm is popup when click the button, but there's nothing changed at the mysql database.

Comment: Can you print or return the result of your mysqli_query() to make sure the query worked correctly?

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: I checked the result of query and printed but, there's nothing show.

Comment: Yes I include before my javascript file

Comment: Yes, this is an online website

Comment: At the request_delete.php i try print out only:

    print $_POST['modify_id'];

But nothing appear. So i think, the post method doesn't work.

Comment: This `<button> onclick='requestD(".$row['modify_id']. ")'>` should be `<button onClick='requestD(".$row['modify_id'].")'>`

Answer (score -1):

remove html code from php, use normaly

and in javascript use == true in condition ( conf == true )..

and for secure your php script use $modify_id = intval($_POST['modify_id'])

if not working triying to print $row['modify_id']
if $row['modify_id'] == anythinf virify your fatch...
thanks

Comment: what html code ? `if (conf){` is completely valid, using intval or not wont fix the issue, this is just a bunch of worng comments, not  an answer

Answer (score -1):

there could be many reasons, not finding the request_delete.php, not sending the parameters, etc. Use the browser developer tools and check the "Network" tab (it's almost the same in FireFox or Chrome). There you'll see if the parameters are sent, if the script is executed and if you got any response. Then you can add output to "request_delete.php" to debug where the error is, and so on